# US phone number validation for four textbox with extension[optional] using jquery validate.js

Tags: jquery

I have one form which contains four textbox phone,phone1,phone2 & ext. For validation I used jquery validate.js. Its working fine but one issue is there, its allowing invalid numbers also like 000-000-0000 or 001-000-0000

***Below is my script for validation:***

```
$params['rules'][$phone] = {"required": true,"minlength": 3,"digits":true };
$params['messages'][$phone] = {"required":"<div class='error-message'>*This is required </div> <div class='error-arrow'></div> ",
"minlength":"<div class='error-message'>*  Numbers should be 3 digits</div> <div class='error-arrow'></div>","digits":" <div class='error-message'>* Numbers only</div> <div class='error-arrow'></div> "};


$params['rules'][$phone2] = {"required": true,"minlength": 3,"digits":true };
$params['messages'][$phone2] = {"required":"<div class='error-message'>* This is required</div> <div class='error-arrow'></div> ",
"minlength":"<div class='error-message'>*  Numbers should be 3 digits</div> <div class='error-arrow'></div>",
"digits":" <div class='error-message'>* Numbers only</div> <div class='error-arrow'></div> "};
```

Comment: Script working for one textbox:  jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
 return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
  phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");